# Obj C Reading Files, txt file not found

Tags: objective-c, file-io

I'm trying to read information from a text file in an Obj. C program and whenever I try to NSLog the output, I'm getting (null).  I've made sure that the text files I'm working with are in my Copy Bundle Resources, which is what all of the other answers I've found have suggested.  I'm using the following to access the files:

```
NSString *rightsPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Sample Maze Rights" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *rightsContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:rightsPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

Can anyone make any suggestions?

Comment: are you sure it is `.txt`?

Comment: Make use of the `error` parameter and log the error.

Answer (score 1):

That's what `error` argument is for.

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *rightsContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:rightsPath
                                                    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                       error:&error];
if (rightsContent == nil)
    NSLog(@"error: %@", [error description]);
```

Comment: Excellent. This code fixes that problem, but the error is showing the following exception: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=258 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 258.)" UserInfo=0x6870930 {}.  Since I've already added the file to my Copy Bundle Resources, can you think of anything else that may be causing the issue?  Thanks!!

Comment: Error code is what you google first, then ask. http://petosoft.wordpress.com/2011/11/15/cocoa-error-258-when-using-stringwithcontentsoffile/ Are you sure path is not nil?

Comment: If your path seems correct, try NSLog'ging it and then run this command in Terminal.app: `ls -l "<path/you/just/got>"` (without angular brackets). This will show you whether file is really there and what permissions are on it. `-r--------` is enough, `-rw-------` is ok too.

Comment: Thanks guys--problem solved!  Turns out after I changed this code I didn't realize that the file I created within XCode didn't have a file type, so I changed its properties and all is well.  Thanks again!

Comment: No no. You mean didn't have a file extension. A file type is about file content, an extension is about the name.  APIs that rely solely on extensions are stupid.

Comment: BTW, calling `[error description]` is redundant. Just NSLog `error` itself. NSLog will call an object's `description` method when it finds a `%@` flag.